# Lighttpd url rewrite not working

Tags: mod-rewrite, lighttpd

Whenever I try `subdomain.localhost/whatever/assets/images/realImage.jpg` it shows mir the image at `folder/assets/images/realImage.jpg` and works like a charme. Also for `subdomain.localhost/whatever/favicon.ico` it presents `folder/favicon.ico`.
But as I try `subdomain.localhost/whatever` it will not give me `folder/sitemap.xml`.

I also tried to debug using `debug.log-request-handling` (will not rewrite the request) and `debug.log-condition-handling` (result: of condition is true). So does anyone have a clue?

This is my lighttpd.conf snipplet (`mod_rewrite` is activated).

```
$HTTP["host"] == "subdomain.localhost" {
    server.document-root = "folder"
    $HTTP["url"] != "test" {
        url.rewrite = (
             "."                                => "/sitemap.xml",
        )
    }
    url.rewrite = (
        "assets/(.*)$"                          => "/assets/$1",
        "(favicon.ico|sitemap.xml|robots.txt)"  => "/$1",
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See  [Support url.rewrite (handle_uri_raw callbacks) in $HTTP["url"] and $HTTP["query-string"]](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/2526) which fixed in 1.4.34.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I figured it out:

http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModRewrite#Description

> NOTE: url rewriting does not work within a $HTTP["url"] conditional.

Comment: Seems to have been added in https://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/2526 (as described in @gavenkoa answer)